# Approach to extract quotations from text and their speakers

Tags: java, regex, machine-learning, nlp, grammar

I want to be able to extract quotations and their speakers from given text. For this, I am following the rules mentioned in section 5.2 of the paper http://langtech.jrc.ec.europa.eu/Documents/0709_RANLP_Quotation-detection_BP-RS-CB_final.pdf

The rules are like:

```
(1) quote-mark QUOTE quote-mark [,] verb [modifier]
[determiner] [title] name
e.g. "blah blah", said again the journalist John Smith.

(2) name [, up to 60 characters ,] verb [:|that] quote-mark
QUOTE quote-mark
e.g. John Smith, supporting AFG, said: "blah blah".

(3) quote-mark QUOTE quote-mark [; or ,] [title] name
[modifier] verb
e.g. "blah blah", Mr John Smith said.
```

The "quote-mark" are general opening and closing quotation marks. A "QUOTE" is actual quotation text, a "modifier" is an adverb, a "verb" is a reporting/communication verb which needs to be present in a lexicon of verbs, "title" and "name" are title and name for persons. The names will be considered as the speaker of quotation.

For each given text, I have a set of NLP annotations indicating which words from text are verbs, adverbs, names and titles.

I am looking for an approach to match the given text and NLP annotations against the rule mentioned above and come up with set of quotations and their speakers from it. I understand that I can write the hardcoded logic to represent these rules but I want to make these rules configurable.

Is there any way to deal with this problem using regex, grammar parsers or some other approach?

Comment: Why don't you just engineer these rules in a rule language like [Jape](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch8.html) or [UIMA Ruta](http://uima.apache.org/ruta.html)?